# Best "Cryptic Clue Chat Chains" (CCCC) Questions

Tags: discussion, chat, best-of

Since November 2016, there has been a game ongoing in [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524) called [Cryptic Clue Chat Chains](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=33518247#33518247).  It involves one person thinking up a [cryptic clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45984/), such as might be found in a [Cryptic Crossword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword), and everyone else trying to solve it.

We have been maintaining an [archive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOR80-CRwBbb7odMLt2QRx_uEIefjovIOjFzZ_2VqoY/edit#gid=1924270515) of these clues, but many excellent clues, especially if they get solved relatively quickly, disappear into the chat transcript and the archive and are rarely seen.

This post is an attempt to highlight some of those excellent clues, and to allow more people to enjoy the ingenuity of some of the excellent puzzle-setters in chat.

If you see (or have seen) a particularly clever or well-constructed cryptic clue in the game, nominate it here.  Hopefully, over time, we will develop a repository of great cryptic clues.

Don't forget to vote on your favourites!

---

Please post one clue per answer.  Answers should be of the following form, without any other content:

---

#### Cryptic clue as it was posed (don't forget the enumeration) — *Author*

> Answer in a spoiler

*Explanation*

> Explanation in a spoiler.  This explains how the answer is derived.

*Description*

> Explanation of what makes this clue so great, or why you think it deserves mention.  Please keep it to 2 or 3 sentences.

Comment: It will continue *until* November 2106 :-)

Comment: Should the setters be credited in these answers? (Yes, because they deserve it. No, because then voting might be influenced by knowing whose clues they are. Not sure how it balances out.)

Comment: @Gareth I suspect that most people who are voting already know who the setter is.  Even if that's not true, almost all other voting on this site is subject to the same bias, so why not allow it here as well?

Comment: I think I think it would be better to credit setters. But I wanted to give both sides of the argument.

Comment: I've made the executive decision and added all the authors.

Answer (score 24):

<sub>***Note***: I'm going to have to bend a few rules with this submission. For example, even though it's technically about a single clue, I'd have to at least mention many other clues for reasons that will be obvious soon.</sub>

#### Regarding potentially common solution to an archived minipuzzle?? (2, 4) — *Sp3000*

> ON TIME

*Explanation*

> First, let's have a look at the "solution to an archived minipuzzle" part. What archive? What minipuzzle? Well, archive refers to the [CCCC archive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOR80-CRwBbb7odMLt2QRx_uEIefjovIOjFzZ_2VqoY/edit#gid=1924270515) put together by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain), but that's not supposed contain a minipuzzle or anything, right?
>
>  Wrong. As [ffao astutely observed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39453103#39453103), Sp3000 (the author of this clue) has been setting some rather unusual clues for the CCCC for the last two months. Here are the clues with answers:
>
> ```
> Help cut commercial for negative neophyte (6) NOVICE
> One rhythmically moved about, five moved forward (8)  ADVANCED
> Deluxe therapy uses water regularly — it's a waste (7)    EXHAUST
> Countless use tin if nickel selection's recalled (8)  INFINITE
> Force it inside cushy sort of train (7)   GRAVITY
> That woman provided nothing but dismissed leads? Wonderful (8)    HEAVENLY
> Greatest saying about Greek character (7) MAXIMUM
> Simple, as in extremely elementary (4)    EASY
> Mother left after Weasley returned - typical (6)  NORMAL
> Shy person, on the inside, is overly excited (5)  HYPER
> Letter from old flame (2) EX
> Pale pickle's pepperless (5)  LIGHT
> Moderate channel (6)  MEDIUM
> Defeat consumed a monster (5) BEAST
> Fear in @GarethM: being wrong (9) NIGHTMARE
> First time out, caught a local train back (5) DEBUT
> Even leaders of alpine race followed sledder going the wrong way (7)  REGULAR
> Naked apron is a plus (3) PRO
> Jack let go from drifting scrap, receding, with first sign of Rose being overcome (6) MASTER
> Nauseous, couple left a piece of cake (4) EASY
> Casual's first to leave without loud type of Pokémon (6)  NORMAL 
> Fragment cut head forcefully (4)  HARD
> Cycling Dino, a silent performer (5)  EXTRA
> Gin and tonic, essentially, consumed by alcohol newbie (8)    BEGINNER
> Hack back, restricting half of site's early programming language (5)  BASIC
> Very loud one in returning type of dream, with time, becomes troublesome (9)  DIFFICULT
> Make an effort to conceal opener of pair ace (6)  EXPERT
> Gabriel perhaps stripped following the lead of Chuck Berry for dare (9)   CHALLENGE
> ```

> ffao figured out that the answers are all difficulty settings of rhythm games. Here are the corresponding games (image courtesy [Deusovi](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=39453319#39453319), click to enlarge):
>  [image]
>  [As noted by Deusovi](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39453296#39453296), if we count the number of difficulty settings for each game, say $n$, and take the $n$th letter from the corresponding game, we get the letters of the answer, ON TIME.
>
>  Now what about the "Regarding potentially common" part? "Regarding" of course means "ON", and "potentially common" denotes TIME, as in [Common time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature).

*Description*

> - The amount of effort and time spent on planning the whole thing, making the clues, sneaking them into the CCCC archive without anyone noticing over a period of two months is not like anything else we've seen so far in CCCC.
> - The individual clues are very well-polished.
> - The overall puzzle, on its own, is clever and enjoyable.
> - The fact that one can be so productive even without the incentive of imaginary internet points, is fairly shocking, to put it lightly.

Answer (score 18):

#### It makes wet god - disgusting! (6) — *Deusovi*

> ROTTEN

*Explanation*

> [ROT(10)](http://www.rot-n.com/) (or ROT TEN) changes *wet* into *god*. Disgusting = ROTTEN. So, it is a double definition.

*Description*

> This clue is one of *those* clues where you just applaud the ingenuity behind it. These quotes will justify why I consider this clue so great.
>  - **Sconibulus**: *"I think I hate you"*
>  - **Alconja**: *"You said I will love it or hate it. Love the clue, hate you"*
>  The above was said to Deusovi and can be found on his profile too.

Answer (score 15):

#### Mistake Gates for Jobs? (7) — *Sp3000*

> ERRANDS

*Explanation*

> ERR(~mistake)+ANDS(~Gates)=ERRANDS(~Jobs)

*Description*

> This is misdirection at its best. In isolation, the first images that the words `Gates` and `Jobs` elicit are rather mundane ones, but there clever positioning in the clue immediately makes us think of two of the biggest names in the tech field. Even if you manage avoid that false lead, you still need to get over your first impression to figure out what `gates` here sneakily hints at.

Answer (score 13):

#### 000-ish (5) — *Deusovi*

> OVOID

*Explanation*

> O(~0)+VOID(~0)=OVOID(~0-ish).

*Description*

> It's unbelievable that there's even a word that's so magnificently clue-able. Sheer brevity, novelty and cleverness make it one of the finest clues ever posed in CCCC.

Comment: Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 6):

### What's missing from my CCCC contributions from July up until now - can you find it?? (1) — *juicifer*

> E

*Explanation*

> This isn't really a proper traditional cryptic clue, but is more a metapuzzle. Each of the previous 25 clues set by juicifer, along with their answers, omit the letter E.  The "can you find it?" part of the clue refers to the clever hiding of the constant **e** in the clues and solutions, as detailed below.

*Description*

> In addition to the omission of the letter E as stated above, juicifer very cleverly hid the constant **e** (sometimes referred to as *Euler's constant*) within the 25 clues previously set.
>  Each clue begins with a distinct letter of the alphabet (except, of course, E). If we order the clues alphabetically, then take the first letter of each clue and find its position in that clue's solution, we end up with the digits of the constant **e**.  (2.718281828459...)
>
>  See the clues and solutions in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KDoediXyBigd7BxKPhE8DLTHYKycDY1m50LS7ai4taE)

Answer (score 3):

#### Crawler trap top spins discourse (7) — *Sconibulus*

> CAPTCHA

**Explanation**

> CAPTCHA = Crawler trap = CAP (top) + (CHAT -> TCHA)

**Why?**

> Well of course we should include the infamous longest standing clue (as of this moment). Some have come close, but none have yet overtaken it. I also think it's a very misleading clue, which are often a sign of a good clue.

Comment: How do you get CAP from crawler trap?

Comment: @ErikE CAP is clued by "top", "Crawler trap" is the definition of the whole answer, CAPTCHA.

Comment: All the others had the whole-answer clue at the end, so I was not expecting it at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

#### I inseminate article of clothing (3) — *Rand al'Thor*

> TIE

**Explanation**

> inseminate = in semi nate = inside half of NATE = inside TE

**Why?**

> Sounds a lot worse than it actually is. [Rand seems to be fairly proud of it too.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=36861794#36861794)

Answer (score 3):

### Not end ends not end, not end ends end (4) — *HTM*

> BUTT

*Explanation*

> [[Not end] ends] [[not end], [not [end ends]] = end
>
>  [[(no)T] comes after] [[DEBUT], [minus [E(n)D]]] = end
>
>  [_T after] [(-de)BUT] = end = BUTT

*Description*

> The clue stands out because it is constructed from only three different words (with two in fact having the same base word)! I still cannot believe that the English language and cryptic clue construction customs, as we know them today, have aligned to make such a beautiful surface possible. Cheers to HTM for bringing that surface into reality.

Answer (score -5):

**An old saw ends like this: part of the precipitate (5) — msh210**

Answer

> Trash

Explanation

> An old saw ends like TRASH (def), and part of the word THE is the letter T, plus RASH, which is an adjective from "precipitate".

Why?

> This is the one which stumped the chat the most. We started talking about chemistry, double definitions, rain patterns, antique tools, music, you name it, it really stumped us. But, once again, @jafe's problem solving skills threw that c4 in the TRASH!